# Add items to cart in php using sessions

Tags: php, jquery, e-commerce

[image: How cat looks like, there are items added twice]Am trying to update the quantity in add to cart session, but the below code only increases the quantity of the first item added twice and then perfoms a merge whenever any other item is added twice, kidly help

```js
$('.add-to-cart-mt').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id =$(this).attr('id');
        $('#add-to-cat-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            modal:true,
            hide:"pluff",
            show:"slide",
            height:200,
            open: function() { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
            
            buttons:{
                "Add":function (){
                    $('#add-to-cat-dialog').dialog("close");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'add_to_cart.php',
                        data: {  productId : id },
                        
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('.top-cart-contain').empty();
                            $('.top-cart-contain').load("header_cart_summary.php");
                        },
                        
                        error :function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  }
                    });
                },
                
                "Cancel":function (){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        
        $('#add-to-cat-dialog').dialog("open");
    });
```

```css
session_start();
require './database.php';

      if(!empty($_GET["productId"])) {
          $id=$_GET["productId"];
            $productById = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId='$id';");
            if($productById && (mysqli_num_rows($productById)>0)){
                echo 'query ok';
                $productDetail= mysqli_fetch_assoc($productById);
                $itemArray = array(
                    $productDetail["productId"]=>array(
                        'name'=>$productDetail["productName"],
                        'id'=>$productDetail["productId"], 
                        'quantity'=>1,
                        'price'=>$productDetail["productPrice"],
                        'image'=>$productDetail["productsImage1"]
                        )
                    );
            
                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    if(in_array($productDetail["productId"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productDetail["productId"] == $k) {
                                  if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                                  }
                                  $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                          $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                    }
                } else {
                      $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                }
                
                //set product count in the bag
                if(!empty($_SESSION['cart_volume'])){
                    $_SESSION['cart_volume'] += 1;
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['cart_volume'] = 1;
                }
                
            }else {echo ''. mysqli_error($connection);}
            
      } else {
          echo 'no item';
}
```

```html
[enter image description here][1]<li class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                  <div class="item-inner">
                                    <div class="product-thumb has-hover-img">
                                      <figure> <a title="Ipsums Dolors Untra" href="single_product.html"> <img class="first-img" src="./productImages/<?php echo $item['productsImage1']; ?>" style="height: 250px;"  alt=""> <img class="hover-img" src="../images/products/img05.jpg" alt=""> </a></figure>
                                      <div class="pr-info-area animated animate2"><a href="quick_view.html" class="quick-view"><i class="fa fa-search"><span>Quick view</span></i></a> <a href="wishlist.html" class="wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart"><span>Wishlist</span></i></a> <a href="compare.html" class="compare"><i class="fa fa-exchange"><span>Compare</span></i></a> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                      <div class="info-inner">
                                        <div class="item-title"> <h4><a title="Ipsums Dolors Untra" href="single_product.html"><?php echo $item['productName']; ?></a></h4> </div>
                                        <div class="item-content">
                                          <div class="rating"> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> </div>
                                          <div class="item-price">
                                            <div class="price-box">
                                              <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label">Special Price</span> <span class="price">Ksh. <?php echo number_format($item['productPrice'], 2) ; ?></span> </p>
                                              <!--<p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span> <span class="price"> $567.00 </span> </p>-->
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="pro-action">
                                              <button type="button" class="add-to-cart-mt" id="<?php echo $item['productId']; ?>"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span> Add to Cart</span> </button>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </li>
```

Comment: Can you make  `var_dump($_GET['productId']);` after adding one item to cart? What does it says?

Comment: string(1) "5" : where 5 is the value of the product Id seemingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works fine as i required. Thanks to -Saleiro for his inputs.

[[image: The correct output as required[1]]

```
  if(!empty($_GET["productId"])) {
      $id=intval($_GET["productId"]);
        $productById = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId='$id' ");
        if($productById && (mysqli_num_rows($productById)>0)){
            $productDetail= mysqli_fetch_assoc($productById);
            $itemArray = array(intval($productDetail["productId"])=>array('name'=>$productDetail["productName"], 'id'=>intval($productDetail["productId"]), 'quantity'=>1, 'price'=>$productDetail["productPrice"]));

            $found = false;
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($productDetail["productId"] == $v['id']) {
                            $found= true;
                            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                  $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                            }
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                if(!$found) {
                      $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                  $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }else {echo ''. mysqli_error($connection);}

         if(!empty($_SESSION['cart_volume'])){
                $_SESSION['cart_volume'] += 1;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['cart_volume'] = 1;
            }

  } else {
      echo 'no item';
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PHP manual: [PHP Manual - array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

The relevant part:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. **If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.**
>
> **Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.**

Probably, You are using numeric ids. If yes, this IDs are transformed into a numerical sequence that does not match the IDs you need (productIDs)

```
$itemArray = array(
    $productDetail["productId"]=>array(
        'name'=>$productDetail["productName"],
        'id'=>$productDetail["productId"], 
        'quantity'=>1,
        'price'=>$productDetail["productPrice"],
        'image'=>$productDetail["productsImage1"]
    )
);
```

Check out locally this code:

```
$a = array('6' => array('name'=>'john','id'=>'6','quantity'=>1));

$b = array('7' => array('name'=>'bill','id'=>'7','quantity'=>1));

$c = array('8' => array('name'=>'mike','id'=>'8','quantity'=>1));

$d = array('6' => array('name'=>'lucy','id'=>'6','quantity'=>1));

$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($a, $b, $c, $d);

var_dump($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);

$a = array('six' => array('name'=>'john','id'=>'6','quantity'=>1));

$b = array('seven' => array('name'=>'bill','id'=>'7','quantity'=>1));

$c = array('eight' => array('name'=>'mike','id'=>'8','quantity'=>1));

$d = array('six' => array('name'=>'lucy','id'=>'6','quantity'=>1));

$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($a, $b, $c, $d);

var_dump($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
```

The result for me was:

```
/am.php:13:
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "john"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "6"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "bill"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "7"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "mike"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "8"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
  [3] =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "lucy"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "6"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
}
/am.php:26:
array(3) {
  'six' =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "lucy"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "6"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
  'seven' =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "bill"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "7"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
  'eight' =>
  array(3) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "mike"
    'id' =>
    string(1) "8"
    'quantity' =>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

This shows how array_merge deals with numeric indexes (at least using PHP 7). As you can see, numeric indexes even typed as strings will be handled like numeric, loosing the productIDs reference.

Another thing: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$id=$_GET["productId"];
$productById = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId='$id';");
```

Read more about it here: [PHP Manual - SQL Injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: sure thing, now, when my problem sounds like the comparison of checking if the product id sent by the $_GET is in the array keys of the $_session[cart_item]. If the comparison fails then i merge the new product in the session. The scenario now is, i click on add to cat on product A the first time, its merged which is the correct thing. When i clicked again on add to cart on product A its merged again which is the wrong thing because already there should be a key with the same product id so it should just increase the quantity.

Comment: I assume that productID is an integer, right? Assuming that, in the first call the product is not in the session array and will be merged by array_merge... as the PHP manual said, if you try to merge arrays with this function and the arrays have numbers as indexes, they will merge the indexes (until here is all ok) and the resulting array (the merged one) will have **new indexes**, using a new numeric values starting from zero! Can you var_dump the session array after the first and second insert of the same product?

Comment: string(1) "6" array(1) { [6]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Laptops" ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(4) "3000" } }

Comment: string(1) "6" array(1) { [6]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Laptops" ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["quantity"]=> int(2) ["price"]=> string(4) "3000" } }

Comment: when i add a new second item: string(1) "7" array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Laptops" ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["quantity"]=> int(2) ["price"]=> string(4) "3000" } [1]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(32) "Computing & Computer Accessories" ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(3) "400" } }

Comment: when i re-add the second item: string(1) "7" array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Laptops" ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["quantity"]=> int(2) ["price"]=> string(4) "3000" } [1]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(32) "Computing & Computer Accessories" ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(3) "400" } [2]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(32) "Computing & Computer Accessories" ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(3) "400" } }

Comment: I edited my answer with an example how array_merge deals with mueric strings indexes. Looks strange that your var_dumps shows strings as array indexes, what PHP version are you using? Another approach are instead of doing array_merge, you can handle the index directly, something like `$_SESSION["cart_item"][$productDetail["productId"]] = $itemArray;`.

Comment: Am using PHP 7.0